# MS Access product manager capacity timeline query/report

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, timeline

This may take a bit of explaining, but I'm trying to figure out if this is a query I haven't figured out how to write, or if this would be better solved with a change in the current structure of the MS Access database I've built.  So with that said...

I have an MS Access database with 3 main tables for this issue:

```
[Products]
[ProductChanges]
[Managers]
```

They are linked like this:

```
[Products].[ID] -> [ProductChanges].[PName]
[Products].[CurrManager] -> [Managers].[ID]
[ProductChanges].[CurrManager] -> [Managers].[ID]
```

The Products table lists all current, past, and future products we service (or will service), and the ProductChanges table contains all changes to that product (movement between managers, status updates, etc.)  I've gotten it to look really nice from a navigation view, each product's form shows its current status, manager, and a subform shows its past and upcoming changes (from the ProductChanges table).

I've also written an update query that runs every time the database is opened that updates the CurrManager field in the Products table based on the dates of the changes in the ProductChanges table, and updates it to the value of the CurrManager field in the ProductChanges table.  Maybe I should change one of those field names, it sounds confusing now that it's typed out.

Here's the tricky part: as new products come our way, we need to know which managers can take on more (they have a max capacity).  Current capacity is easy, querying the Products table's field 'CurrManager' and counting the ID's of the products assigned to them as of right now, but we need to see who will have capacity in the future, preferably in a timeline format.  Since products change hands a lot (and some finish and move on to somewhere else), the number of products each manager is overseeing will change as the database updates itself based on the dates in the ProductChanges table.

So an example of a final output ideally would be something like:

```
          1/1/2016 | 1/8/2016 | 1/15/2016
Smith, J  10         12         9
```

Depending on how many products were scheduled to either be assigned to J. Smith or move on from J. Smith between those dates.  A "Capacity by Week" essentially.  I've made some progress but have been hung up for a while.  This query will get me a basic timeline of history, but I can't seem to get it to sum up a portfolio for date ranges:

```
SELECT Managers.LastName
    ,Managers.FirstName
    ,ProductChanges.Effectivedate
    ,[ProductChanges].[EffectiveDate] - Weekday([ProductChanges].[EffectiveDate]) + 1 AS [Week Of]
    ,Count(Products.Name) AS NumProducts
FROM Managers
RIGHT JOIN (
    Products INNER JOIN (
        ProductChanges LEFT JOIN Managers AS Managers_1 ON ProductChanges.CurrManager = Managers_1.ID
        ) ON Products.ID = ProductChanges.InnCode
    ) ON Managers.ID = Products.CurrManager
    ,Managers.FirstName
    ,ProductChanges.Effectivedate
    ,[ProductChanges].[EffectiveDate] - Weekday([ProductChanges].[EffectiveDate]) + 1
HAVING (
        ((Managers.LastName) IS NOT NULL)
        AND ((ProductChanges.Effectivedate) > 0)
        )
ORDER BY Managers.LastName;
```

It's a mess, I know, so if (and when) clarification is needed, I'll be watching this one pretty closely.

Comment: I can't imagine that having so many nested joins is the direction you want to be going in.

Comment: I was wondering if I needed so many, but it started morphing into a monster trying to get closer to what I need...which is why I'm thinking I may need a structure change or some other table to organize it.

Comment: My suggestion, besides your current query just show us sample input along with expected output after the join.  This will be way more helpful than paragraphs of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it!  It ended up being a 2 step process to get what I needed it to do, but so long as the records are up to date for the product changes, this shows me an actual timeline of a manager gaining and losing products.

The main reason I had to do it this way is that the user has the ability to change a product's past history in the case there is something missing, which means that the record ID's in the ProductChanges table can be considered essentially random in relation to the EffectiveDate field, making a running total query on just the ProductChanges table almost but not quite work for managers whose product change histories had been changed.  I wrote a quick script to build a table specifically for ordering the ID's the way I needed:

`Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDB
db.Execute "DROP TABLE GainLoss;"
db.Execute "CREATE TABLE GainLoss(AutoID AutoIncrement, HCID Long, MgrID Long, LastName varchar(100), FirstName varchar(100), HCDate Date, GainLoss Long)"
db.Execute "INSERT INTO GainLoss(HCID, MgrID, LastName, FirstName, HCDate, GainLoss) SELECT hc.ID, s.ID, s.LastName, s.FirstName, hc.EffectiveDate, iif(s.id = hc.currmanager,1,-1) FROM Managers s INNER JOIN ProductChanges hc ON (s.ID = hc.currmanager OR s.ID = hc.prevmanager) ORDER BY LastName, FirstName, EffectiveDate;"`

Which also gives me a plus one for each product that a manager gets, and a minus one for each one they pass on.  Throw that through this query:

`SELECT A.AutoID, A.MgrID, A.LastName, A.FirstName, A.HCDate, Sum(B.GainLoss) AS Capacity
FROM GainLoss AS A LEFT JOIN GainLoss AS B ON (A.AutoID >= B.AutoID) AND (A.MgrID = B.MgrID) AND (A.HCDate >= B.HCDate)
GROUP BY A.LastName, A.FirstName, A.MgrID, A.HCDate, A.AutoID;`

And you've got a timeline showing every change either adding or subtracting a product to a manager's portfolio.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a [crosstab query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465b89c-2ff2-4cc8-ba60-2cd8484667e8) (a unique MS Access SQL query not available in other RDMS's) which pivots data along column of values (i.e., effective dates) running any aggregate (Count, Sum, Avg, Min, Max, etc.).

Below joins all three *Managers*, *ProductChanges*, and *Products* tables in aggregate query. Adjust as needed according to your schema. In MSAccess.exe you can adjust the crosstab in Design View selecting the *Row Heading* (one or more), *Column Heading* (only one), and *Value* (only one) fields:

```
TRANSFORM Count(p.InnCode) AS NumProducts
SELECT m.LastName, m.FirstName
FROM (Managers m
INNER JOIN ProductChanges pc
    ON m.[ID] = pc.[CurrManager])
INNER JOIN Products p
    ON pc.[PName] = p.[ID]
GROUP BY m.LastName, m.FirstName
PIVOT pc.Effectivedate
```

Do note: MS Access tables/queries have a limit of 255 columns. So if you run into more than 254 unique dates, you will need to filter which can be handled with `PIVOT Column IN()` clause. Consider even passing current next 3-4 weeks dynamically by VBA parameters.

```
TRANSFORM Count(p.InnCode) AS NumProducts
SELECT m.LastName, m.FirstName
FROM (Managers m
INNER JOIN ProductChanges pc
    ON m.[ID] = pc.[CurrManager])
INNER JOIN Products p
    ON pc.[PName] = p.[ID]
GROUP BY m.LastName, m.FirstName
PIVOT pc.Effectivedate IN ('1/1/2016', '1/8/2016', '1/15/2016')
```

Comment: This is pretty close!  I hadn't tried cross-tab queries yet, or I guess haven't had the need for them.  I think with some tweaking of what you've started me with this should get me there.  Thanks!

Comment: Great! Yes, play around with it. Only you know your schema. Joins should work but not subqueries. Notice a compliant aggregate query in the middle. You can add aggregates as rows, too. Please accept answer if helpful and to confirm resolution.

Comment: I may need more help with aggregates on rows, I could only get the crosstab to show number of changes.  I also got to this via the interwebs which gets extremely close:

`SELECT A.ID, S.ID, S.LastName, S.FirstName, A.EffectiveDate, Count(B.ID) AS PGains
FROM Managers AS S LEFT JOIN (ProductChanges AS A LEFT JOIN ProductChanges AS B ON (A.EffectiveDate >= B.EffectiveDate) AND (A.CurrManager = B.CurrManager)) ON S.ID = A.CurrManager
GROUP BY A.ID, S.ID, S.LastName, S.FirstName, A.EffectiveDate, A.ID
HAVING (((A.ID) Is Not Null))
ORDER BY S.LastName, S.FirstName, A.EffectiveDate, A.ID;`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to query your table and add a field that converts the date to the "week of" similar to what you did with

```
ProductChanges.EffectiveDate - Weekday(ProductChanges.EffectiveDate) + 1
```

From that point, it's just a simple query grouping by this field - after you JOIN all the other tables you need to your ProductChanges table.